# wsimport try to resolve by namespace

Tags: service, jax-ws, svcutil.exe, wsimport

Is it possible for wsimport to ignore "import" tags in wsdl that are http-linked to some XSD files and insted use XSD files provided next to the wsdl file?. I know svcutil is able to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an XML catalog to help tell wsimport how/where to resolve schema elements.

[xmlcatalog ant docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/xmlcatalog.html)

defines the xmlcatalog task for ant.  you can reference the catalog via the "catalog" attribute of the wsimport ant task, or via the -catalog command line option of wsimport.

[jaxws xml catalog docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/catalog.html)

I hope this helps.